# Displaying pdf in iframe not working properly in iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, iframe, scroll

I am trying to display pdf in iPad using iframe, Pdf is displayed in ipad but not able to scroll the view. 
I have also tried with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; but it of no use.

I would appreciate if anyone can give me a better way of embedding the pdf file in html with ipad support

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to scroll the embeded content as soon as your iframe has overflow:scroll property, but you may not be able to see the scrollbars

Another solution is to place the following javascript code inside the content which you would like to be able to scroll:

```
this.height=100%;
```